# Gridview row count with condition

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a gridview which is bounded with a combobox and when an item in the combobox is selected the gridview shows the data.

I want to know the number of male and female from gridview in 2 labels but I couldn't find a good solution please give me tips or code?

Comment: Please provide the relevant code you have so far, and show us where you are having problems.

Comment: @DeanOC: i just posted the code please go through..

Comment: what does  `da1.Fill(ds).ToString()` do?

Comment: bind the `dataGridView1.DataSource` after `da1.Fill(ds)`.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh when i remove the Fill(ds) part from last line it shows the following in the lable "syste.data.oledb.oledbdataadaptor"

Comment: yes, becasuse `da1` is of type `syste.data.oledb.oledbdataadaptor`

Comment: try to set it to `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count`.Make sure `ds.Tables[0]` is not null.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: i already have done that but it returns total num of fields in the gridview, what i want is the number of females in the gridview.

Comment: by the way your query returns a number only.How are you populating a grid?

Comment: a dataset for storing a number?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh the answer given below bro, looks like i didn't need any datased or somethings, thanks

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh he already has data in `ds.Tables[0]` that is going to grid and just to get the females count only he has come to the database side which is not required ;)

Comment: well .. hmm .. @Vanest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just need these 3 lines for your requirement, and not any database operations.

```
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    lbltotalfemale.Text = ds.Tables[0].Select("Gender='female'")
                                      .Count().ToString();
    lbltotalmale.Text = ds.Tables[0].Select("Gender='male'")
                                    .Count().ToString();
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: thanks it works but I Need total number of females in the gridview, this gives the exact value from the row!

Comment: @Vanest - see the `query1` he has with him.It returns just a count .

Comment: @Vanest - what does `ds.Tables[0]` returns?

Comment: `ds.Tables[0]` is nothing but a `DataTable`

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh it returns the data in the 1st table within the dataset..

Comment: @vanest my bad man! I thought he's executing the query for the first time, Got it all wrong